# ArcGIS / Line width in map units?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I want to change the width of line features.

Is it possible to set the parameter in map units (meter) and not in pixels?

I know that I can apply a buffer to get the same result. But I think it should be possible to do that directly.

Comment: Do you want to change the line width for symbology or you want to save it as a new layer?

Comment: You need to set a reference scale to your data frame if you want to do that. Otherwise the line width on your screen is the same at all scales, and its witdh in map units will vary.

Comment: Yes I know, the reference scale is supposed to be 1:10000. But how can I get the line to have a width of exactly 10 meters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by selecting the symbol from the table of content `-> Symbol Selector -> Edit Symbol -> Properties -> Units` You can change the unit from Points to Inches, Centimeters, or Millimeters:

[image]

If the map unit in meter, then millimeter or centimeter is the one you can choose from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want the line to be f.e. 10 meters width in a scale 1:10000.

Comment: @shrhkn You did not mention anything about scale in your question. You asked how to change the unit of line width from pixel to map unit (meter).

Comment: Sorry, I am just too stupid :) I just have to calculate ^^ So if I want the line to be 10 m, it is 1 mm in a reference scale of 1:10000

Answer (score 2):

Add a new field to your feature class to record the line width, and populate with the value you want to use for each line (eg `10` for 10 meters, or different values if you want to see each line a different size).

[image]

Open the layer properties, and choose the Symbology tab.  In the *Show:* box on the left, expand *Quantities* and select *Proportional symbols*.

For *Value* select the field you added, choose `Meters` for *Unit*, and `Width` under *Data represents*.  This will make your lines draw at the width specified in your new field, in meters.

[image]

Click OK and your lines should now symbolise based on those settings.

1:10000
[image]

Zoomed in to 1:1000 to show the size change relative to the scale:
[image]

Comment: Can anyone answer what data type this needs to be set as to display? and in the same vein how to avoid it defaulting to "null" rather than entering the value needed in the field?

Comment: @SPG it must be a numeric data type such as Integer